AG Grid: In a treeList, can you hide (filter) all children yet still show the parent?
AG Grid: In a treeList, can you hide (filter) all children yet still show the parent?
Background: We have this problem:

We are using AG Grid's tree data model. As demonstratable on the documentation site, it supports the following:

However, when removing the last visible child node (here: Adelaide), the parent (Alejandro) is also hidden (as well as its parents, completely emptying the list in this example). In our use case, this is not desirable, as the parent nodes are valuable on their own.
So:, is it possible to avoid the automatic hiding of the parent?
